# Nvidia graphics card not shown in additional drivers in software sources

Tags: nvidia, 12.10

I don't have my nvidia 8400gm graphics card included in additional drivers in ubuntu 12.10 64bit. Previously it was working fine on ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit. here is the [screenshot](http://ubuntuone.com/3b4bYVUO7du4lcXGe30HSw)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install nVidia newest driver, you need to install the driver manually from terminal.

Open terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+T`) then type this:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

It will install the nVidia latest stable driver.